# Software installation:--add-needed

Tags: installation, openfoam

I am having hard time installing OpenFoam from source. When I execute `./Allwmake` I get the following error message:

> --add-needed is not supported but is required for libopen-rte.so.20 in libmpi.so

I have searched forums for similar `--add-needed` problems but couldn't find anything useful. What is the problem here?

Comment: Is there any chance for you to give some feedback on the answer, if possible? As it seems, the answer does not fulfil your needs?

Comment: Back then i had problem with installing via docker. On second try, I managed to install via docker easily somehow. So I won't be able to give feedback for now.

Comment: If the answers to this question could not be evaluated any longer by yourself, I kindly encourage you to delete the question, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer was given [herein](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/blogs/hisham/2027-error-compiling-openfoam-linker-error-ld-add-needed-not-supported.html) by 'Hisham':

> The 'nixOS has two linker programs ld.bfd and ld.gold. ... (If) ld.gold (exists), the error occurs because the gold version does 
>   not support the --add-needed.

Check the type of linker that the system uses:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ld*
```

If `/usr/bin/ld.gold` exists, remove the following:

```
(sudo) rm /usr/bin/ld 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ld.bfd /usr/bin/ld
```

Then proceed OpenFOAM installation.